# $injector not resolving required modules in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am writing Unit Test Case using Jasmine for angular, but its not resolving dependency for my module. Could you please let me know if i am doing any thing wrong here. Below is the complete link of the snippet.

https://gist.github.com/rahulsahay19/041ca130d187e2a6009e

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: have you added `ui-bootstrap` file in your karma config ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having problem in another angular file where in where in global scope i was using like

var module = angular.module("movieReviewEdit", []);

after renaming the same as shown below, it got fixed.

var movieReviewmodule = angular.module("movieReviewEdit", []);

Thanks,
Rahul